# Twitter4J exception on verifyCredentials

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am creating an Android app that uses Twitter4J to read some user info.

This was all working fine, but this evening when I start the app and the user logs on to Twitter I get an exception:

```
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(twitterID,twitterPassword);
    u = twitter.verifyCredentials();
```

This throws the following exception on the verifyCredentials() call:

```
08-31 20:36:59.084: WARN/System.err(454): twitter4j.TwitterException: https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json
08-31 20:36:59.094: WARN/System.err(454):     at twitter4j.http.HttpClient.request(HttpClient.java:333)
08-31 20:36:59.094: WARN/System.err(454):     at twitter4j.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:66)
08-31 20:36:59.094: WARN/System.err(454):     at twitter4j.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:88)
08-31 20:36:59.094: WARN/System.err(454):     at twitter4j.Twitter.verifyCredentials(Twitter.java:1025)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at com.tmm.android.soundbiter.TwitterInterface.<init>(TwitterInterface.java:65)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at com.tmm.android.soundbiter.LogOnActivity.initTwitterUser(LogOnActivity.java:138)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at com.tmm.android.soundbiter.LogOnActivity.startApplicationActivity(LogOnActivity.java:102)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at com.tmm.android.soundbiter.LogOnActivity.onCreate(LogOnActivity.java:47)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-31 20:36:59.104: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-31 20:36:59.115: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-31 20:36:59.115: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 20:36:59.115: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-31 20:36:59.115: WARN/System.err(454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-31 20:36:59.124: WARN/System.err(454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 20:36:59.124: WARN/System.err(454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-31 20:36:59.124: WARN/System.err(454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-31 20:36:59.124: WARN/System.err(454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-31 20:36:59.134: WARN/System.err(454):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 20:36:59.134: WARN/System.err(454): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json
08-31 20:36:59.134: WARN/System.err(454):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
08-31 20:36:59.134: WARN/System.err(454):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnection.java:252)
08-31 20:36:59.134: WARN/System.err(454):     at twitter4j.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:83)
08-31 20:36:59.134: WARN/System.err(454):     at twitter4j.http.HttpClient.request(HttpClient.java:288)
08-31 20:36:59.134: WARN/System.err(454):     ... 20 more
```

As I mentioned, this has not changed for weeks, but has just suddenly stopped working.. I have also noticed that if I instantiate my Twitter object annonymously (dont pass username and password) then it still allows me to retrieve information/users/statuses from twitter (obviously verifyCredentials() does not work here though as it is an anonymous user)

Has anyone experienced this issue or similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could check this OAuth TUT: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/sending-a-tweet-t54389.html Shows how to use Twitter4J with source files

Comment: Thanks, I actually managed to get it working some time ago, and wrote up what i did here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API no longer supports Basic Authentication, you must change your application to use OAuth, http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth_overview , which is built into Twitter4J also.

Comment: Thanks!  I will investigate this option.. Is this something twitter has only just introduced? this was working just yesterday..

Comment: They had announced they would be doing this a while back, and were actually going to do it some time in July but delayed it for the World Cup.  It was quite easy to overlook.

Comment: Thanks again - I have been looking at the OAuth setup; for my android app, I want users to be able to login to Twitter using their credentials and then be able to post updates etc - do you know if this is possible? Im walking through the steps to get it up and running and I have just had to enter a PIN in to allow the app to access my Twitter account, will all users have to do this? do all Twitter clients have to go through this process?

Comment: Further to the above, having experimented with OAuth I am still getting the same error from twitter.. any ideas?

Comment: looks like im not the only one with the problem this week... HTC having the same problem - will investigate my oauth solution
 
http://www.engadget.com/2010/09/01/htc-peep-cooked-served-a-lorange-by-twitters-new-authenticati/