# Twitter4j Android FileNotFoundException by executing "getFollowersIDs" or "getDirectMessages"

Tags: android, basic-authentication, filenotfoundexception, twitter4j

I use twitter4j on my Android 1.6 phone to request user related data such as all new direct messages or follower ids. It works fine if I only request trends or other user **unrelated** information (trends for example) but if I try to query information such as the follower ids or new direct messages twitter4j throws an TwitterException with the following cause

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json
```

I create an instance of twitter with the following code:

```
TwitterFactory twitterFax = new TwitterFactory();
twitterInstance = twitterFax.getInstance(USERNAME, USER_PASSWORD);
```

The exception throws here:

```
try {

     ResponseList<DirectMessage> directMessages = twitterInstance.getDirectMessages();

     if(directMessages.size() > 0){

        publishProgress(directMessages.toArray());
     }

} catch (TwitterException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twitter API doesn't support simple authentication anymore (you also didn't verify them as well), use OAuth:

http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#oauth

Also see: [Twitter4J exception on verifyCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613150/twitter4j-exception-on-verifycredentials)

Comment: Thx that was the problem. Is there a way to do the pin request inside the code if I have both the Twitter App keys and the user authentication username/password?

Comment: Not sure. What I'm doing is to provide a text input field for the pin and a button below that opens the twitter auth url in the browser where the user will see the pin. He would need to go back to the app manually and enter the pin there. Haven't found a way to automate it yet. Instead of opening the browser, you could maybe open a webview beneath the pin input field, to make it more convenient and user doesn't have to leave the screen.

Comment: Okay - I think I have solved the problem simply through using the generated tokens for my developer account. Fortunately I need no other user to login into my application.